# Setting colours in plotly R is not working (factors) in add markers

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to set the colour in R for "points" or markers in plotly with a custom palette. It doesn't work. I'm also trying to add a title to the graph, but it won't appear. In addition, I'd like to remove some elements of the legend (like the extra "z") and add a title to the legend elements. Nothing seems to work, even if it is present in the code.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123456)
pal <- c("black", "orange", "darkgreen", "pink")
pal <- setNames(pal, levels(as.factor(c("gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4"))))

linedat = data.frame(x = rep(mean(1:50),2),
                         y = rep(mean(1:50),2),
                         z = c(0,1))

zoom = 3
pg = plotly::plot_ly(x = 1:50, 
                     y = 1:50, 
                     z = outer(1:50,1:50,"+")/100) %>% 
  add_surface(contours = list(
    z = list(show = TRUE, start = 0, end = 1, size = 0.05)), 
    opacity = 1) %>%  
  add_markers(x = rnorm(50,25,5),
              y = rnorm(50,25,5),
              marker = list(opacity = 0.9),
              type="scatter3d",
              mode = "markers",inherit = FALSE,
              colors = pal,
              color = as.factor(sample(1:4,50,replace = T)),
              z = rbinom(50,1,.5)) %>% 
  layout(scene=list(title = "Title won't show up????", 
                    xaxis = list(title = 'trait1'), 
                    yaxis = list(title = 'trait1',autorange = "reversed"), 
                    camera = list(eye = list(x = cos(0.8*pi)*zoom, y = sin(pi*1.3)*zoom, z= 2.00)),
                    legend = list(title=list(text='<b> Groups </b>')))) %>% 
  add_trace(data=linedat, x=~x, y=~y, z=~z,
            type="scatter3d", mode="lines", 
            line = list(color = pal[1], 
                        width = 14),name = "Avg. data1")%>% 
  add_trace(data=linedat, x=~x+20, y=~y+20, z=~z, 
            type="scatter3d", mode="lines", 
            line = list(color = pal[4], 
                        width = 14),name = "Avg. data2")
pg
```

[image]

See how here I'm able to set the colour of the points, but I'm not able to get the names of the colours to show in the legend (I modified the code to match what @Kat suggested):

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123456)
pal <- c("black", "orange", "darkgreen", "pink")
pal <- setNames(pal, levels(as.factor(c("gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4"))))

linedat = data.frame(x = rep(mean(1:50),2),
                         y = rep(mean(1:50),2),
                         z = c(0,1))

zoom = 3
pg = plotly::plot_ly(x = 1:50, 
                     y = 1:50, 
                     z = outer(1:50,1:50,"+")/100) %>% 
  add_surface(contours = list(
    z = list(show = TRUE, start = 0, end = 1, size = 0.05)), 
    opacity = 1, colorbar = list(title = "Only one Z")) %>%  
  add_markers(x = rnorm(50,25,5),
              y = rnorm(50,25,5),
              marker = list(color = pal[as.factor(sample(1:4,50,replace = T))],opacity = 0.9),
              type="scatter3d",
              mode = "markers",inherit = FALSE,
              colors = pal,
              
              z = rbinom(50,1,.5)) %>% 
  layout(title = "Title that won't show",
         margin = list(t = 40),
         legend = list(title = list(
           text = "<br>Legends deserve names, too")),
         scene=list(xaxis = list(title = 'trait1'), 
                    yaxis = list(title = 'trait1',autorange = "reversed"), 
                    camera = list(eye = list(x = cos(0.8*pi)*zoom, 
                                             y = sin(pi*1.3)*zoom, z= 2.00)))) %>% 
  add_trace(data=linedat, x=~x, y=~y, z=~z,
            type="scatter3d", mode="lines", 
            line = list(color = pal[1], 
                        width = 14),name = "Avg. data1")%>% 
  add_trace(data=linedat, x=~x+20, y=~y+20, z=~z, 
            type="scatter3d", mode="lines", 
            line = list(color = pal[4], 
                        width = 14),name = "Avg. data2");pg
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original `plot_ly` call and `add_trace` calls can remain as is. I've included the changes needed for the `layout` call and added the call needed for `colorbar`.

The layout first.

```
layout(title = "Title that won't show",       # <------ give my plot a name
         margin = list(t = 40),                 # don't smash that title, either
         legend = list(title = list(
           text = "<br>Legends deserve names, too")), # <--- name my legend
         scene=list(title = "Title won't show up????", # <- this can go away
                    xaxis = list(title = 'trait1'), 
                    yaxis = list(title = 'trait1',autorange = "reversed"), 
                    camera = list(eye = list(x = cos(0.8*pi)*zoom, 
                                             y = sin(pi*1.3)*zoom, z= 2.00)),
                    legend = list(title=list(text='<b> Groups </b>')))) %>% 
  colorbar(title = "Only one Z")          # <--- give me one z colorbar title
```

[image]

(Some colors are different in the image; I didn't realize I had the  `pal` object...sigh)

---

---

#### Update

This addresses your additional questions.

First, I'm not getting an error from the method in which I title the color bar. You'll have to share what error you're getting.

I didn't realize that it was ignoring the colors you set in markers, either. The easiest way to address this is to call that trace first. Since nothing else was declared within `markers`, I called opacity outside of the list, but it's fine the way you have it.

First, I commented out the `setNames` call, because that won't work for the marker's trace and it doesn't matter to the other traces.

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(123456)
pal <- c("black", "orange", "darkgreen", "pink")
# pal <- setNames(pal, levels(as.factor(c("gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4")))) 

linedat = data.frame(x = rep(mean(1:50),2),
                     y = rep(mean(1:50),2),
                     z = c(0,1))
zoom = 3
```

I made `plot_ly()` empty and put all the data for the surface in that trace. I also added `inherit = false` so that the layout could go at the end without the data errors.

```
set.seed(123456)
pg = plotly::plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(inherit = F,
            x = rnorm(50,25,5),
            y = rnorm(50,25,5),
            type="scatter3d",
            mode = "markers",
            opacity = .8,
            colors = pal,
            color = as.factor(sample(1:4, 50, replace = T)),
            z = rbinom(50,1,.5)) %>% 
  add_surface(x = 1:50, 
              y = 1:50, 
              z = outer(1:50,1:50,"+")/100,
              colorscale = "Viridis",
              contours = list(
                z = list(show = TRUE, start = 0, end = 1, size = 0.05)), 
              opacity = 1) %>%  
  add_trace(data=linedat, x=~x, y=~y, z=~z,
            type="scatter3d", mode="lines", 
            line = list(color = pal[1], 
                        width = 14),name = "Avg. data1", inherit = F) %>% 
  add_trace(data=linedat, x=~x+20, y=~y+20, z=~z, 
            type="scatter3d", mode="lines", 
            line = list(color = pal[4], 
                        width = 14),name = "Avg. data2", inherit = F) %>%
```

The last part is the layout, but this is not different than my original answer.

```
  layout(title = "Title that won't show",       # <------ give my plot a name!
         margin = list(t = 40),                 # don't smash that title, either
         legend = list(title = list(
           text = "<br>Legends deserve names, too"),
           tracegroupgap = 350), # <--- name my legend!
         scene=list(title = "Title won't show up????",   # <--- this can go away!
                    xaxis = list(title = 'trait1'), 
                    yaxis = list(title = 'trait1',autorange = "reversed"), 
                    camera = list(eye = list(x = cos(0.8*pi)*zoom, 
                                             y = sin(pi*1.3)*zoom, z= 2.00)),
                    legend = list(title=list(text='<b> Groups </b>')))) %>% 
  
  colorbar(title = "Only one Z")      # <--- give me one z for the title!
pg
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice! Just need to colour to be under control and it'd be amazing. And how would one go about grouping the "Avg. data" under one legend title? For the colours, if I do `marker = list(color = as.factor(sample(1:4,50,replace = T)),opacity = 0.9),` I lose all details of the "1, 2, 3, and 4" grouping all the data under `trace 1`, but showing different colours... I want different colours but also to show them in the legend.

Comment: Why do you want to move the colors to the markers? I guess perhaps I could help more if I understood the objective a bit better.

Comment: I use  custom colours (see `pal`). But I can't colour the markers based on that custom palette. Is there a way to tell plotly to use the palette to colour the markers and then show the elements in the legend?

Comment: I modified the question to show that when I try to set the colour manually, the legend collapses all the different categories to `trace 1`. How then to get the colours associated with the `pal <- setNames(pal, levels(as.factor(c("gr1","gr2","gr3","gr4"))))`?

Comment: In addition, I realized that the `colorbar = list(title = "Only one Z")` should go into the `add_surface` function. Otherwise, it gives a warning.

Comment: I've updated my answer so that you get the colors you want. I don't know why the method I've shown would give you an error for the color bar title. What error are you getting?

Comment: Well, now it seems to work. I got a warning saying that 'contour' wasn't supported, but now it is gone. Thanks a lot, this was extremely helpful! Perhaps something was fixed in between.